Idempotent Armendariz ring property is inherited by polynomial ring
A ring $R$ is said to be idempotent Armendariz if whenever $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then each $a_i b_j$ is idempotent, where $a_i$ are the  coefficients of $f(x)$, and $b_j$ are the coefficients of $g(x)$.
Then how to proceed to prove that if $R$ is idempotent Armendariz then $R[x]$ is idempotent Armendariz?
My attempt: Let us take two polynomials $f(y),g(y)\in R[x][y]$ such that $f(y)g(y)=0$ where $f(y)=f_0+f_1y+...+f_ny^n$ and $g(y)=g_0+g_1y+...+g_my^m$ and $f_i,g_j\in R[x]$ now by simple computation by taking $t=degf_0+...+degg_m$, we turn the polynomials $f(y)g(y)$ into $f(x^t)g(x^t)=0$, so that we get $a_ib_j$ as idempotent due to $R$ being idempotent Armendariz.
Now our claim is $f_ig_j$ is idempotent, to prove this let us take $(f_ig_j)^2=((a_0b_0)+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)y+...(a_nb_m)y^{n+m}$). The problem is by only using $a_ib_j$ is idempotent, I am unable to prove this because there are terms involving $y^2$

If you are asking about general ring properties then the  question is too broad. If you are asking about that specific property then please edit the question to restrict it to that.

I am asking about idempotent Armendariz only, should I edit the question

Yes, as I said.

And what have you tried? I assume you are familiar (after 5 years of membership) with the site guidelines, pure problem statement questions are not supported. As a mini-hint, rename the variable to $y$ and work with $R[y]$ instead, so that you deal with polynomials in $R[y][x] \cong R[x,y]$.
